# `sudoers` file resets with every macOS update

Tags: macos

I had updated my `sudoers` file to make some command run with root privileges by default without the need to use `sudo` and entering my password. I used the command `sudo visudo` and added this line to it:

```
<my_username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: <path/to/command --arguments>
```

But whenever I update macOS, my `sudoers` file is reset to its defaults. A folder named `Relocated Items` appears on my Desktop and it always includes the following file: `/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Configuration/private/etc/sudoers`. This happens on macOS Catalina, and also on macOS Big Sur.

[image: Screen shot from Relocated Items folder]

How can I prevent the `sudoers` file resetting to its defaults with every macOS update?

Comment: How do you update macOS? Just by running the Installer from Finder or by doing a full install via Recovery?

Comment: Don't modify `/etc/sudoers`, but add a file to `/etc/sudoers.d` instead. `sudoers` is configured to read files in that path and apply any rules defined in them. I'd recommend that you name files in `/etc/sudoers.d` after the user they apply to, for example, if your username is `behdad`, `/etc/sudoers.d/behdad`. You can create the file with `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/behdad`.

Comment: What @nohillside said.  I update all the time without having `sudoers` touched in any way

Comment: @nohillside I update macOS using the `.pkg` file downloaded from Apple Support website. I sometimes update using Software Update in System Preferences. In short, I don't do a clean install.

Comment: Interesting. I‘ve been doing this for years and never had an issue with the sudoers file. But the answer below offers a safe way for custom modifications, I might change to that as well.

Comment: @nohillside I've been wondering about this lately. I almost always download the "Combo" update file from Apple website and update my Macs using that. Maybe Combo updates have some sort of validation (and correction?) on some OS files, including the `sudoers` file?

Comment: FWIW I'm getting this behaviour and I only ever update using the 'Software Update' tool. However my OSX install is aeons old, probably originally updated from Snow Leopard to each OSX release in turn, and ported to three successive new computers over about 14 years with Time Machine. I often wonder if that is a factor ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Modifying most of the files in `/etc` leaves you open to them being replaced during OS updates. That's why most of the ones you usually need to change have the facility to add files to a directory instead.

If you look in `/etc` you will see a directory called `sudoers.d` and the last line of the `sudoers` file is `#includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d` so any file of commands you put into the directory will be read. Files in the directory *will not* be overwritten when you update.

You may notice directories with similar names in `/etc` that fill the same function for other parts of the system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So my understanding is that any valid text file in the `sudoers.d` folder (by `visudo` standards) is inserted at the place of #includedir in the `/etc/sudoers` file, right?

Comment: Correct @Behdad